# How to route WSL2 traffic through VPN?

Tags: ssh, vpn, routing, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using WSL2 on Windows 11 x64 for software development. I want to have WSL2 traffic routed through my school's VPN service using Aruba VIA, as I need to SSH into a server and mount network drives when I'm working from home, but don't want to use school resources for other stuff (watching Netflix etc on Windows) as the network drives need to stay mounted for a long time.

This might be done as non-intrusively as possible if I can enable VPN for only port 22 (SSH) and 2049 (NFS).

I also want to have a script that switches between system-wide VPN and WSL2-only VPN, if possible.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried just installing a compatible VPN service within the Linux instance? In other words it shouldn’t be different from a physical Linux installation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, as @Ramhound suggested, I had to install Aruba VIA on WSL. I tried it before with no success, as I didn't know VIA installs a service which depends on the existence of `systemd`, which is not present on WSL and has to be enabled. So, the process of installing Aruba VIA on WSL2 is as follows (as tested on Ubuntu 20.04):

1. Enable systemd on WSL2 using [systemd-genie](https://gist.github.com/djfdyuruiry/6720faa3f9fc59bfdf6284ee1f41f950)
2. Start a systemd-enabled shell
3. Install Aruba VIA installation package using `apt` or `dpkg`
4. Connect to VPN with: `via-cli session start && via-cli vpn connect --username USERNAME --userpass PASSWORD`

Using `via-ui` with WSLg turned out to be not possible for me, as it gave me errors:

```
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display :0
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin
"xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform 
plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application
may fix this problem.
```